# How to implement Search function for a listView that is implemented on ListFragment?

Tags: android, listview, search, inline, android-listfragment

my files:
callListFragment.java --> extends ListFragment

MemberListAdapter.java -->extends ArrayAdapter
(inner class in MemberListAdapter - view holder)

memberViewModel.java ->profile picture icon, full name, email address.

fragment_calllist.xml
calllist_item.xml

need to implement search function for the listView in callListFragment.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] please by [edit] your question

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a EditText to the listFragment class.
2. add the below code in searchMembers.
3. call searchMembers in onCreateView method.

   ```
   searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
           // When user changed the Text
           yourListFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
       }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                     int arg3) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }
   });
   ```